# KDE Plasma 5.25, X11, Breeze (dark): Enable transparency and blur

Tags: fedora, kde, theme, plasma

I recently switched to Fedora KDE 36, with Plasma 5.25.2. Using X11, because I'm experiencing bad visual glitches with Wayland (NVIDIA GPU).

Now I would like to enable some form of **transparency+blur** on Plasma's Breeze theme (dark). I have been searching for some time now, but I have not found a solution that is applicable/up-to-date.
Here's what I tried:

- Go to `System Settings -> Appearance -> Application Style`, click the `Configure style` button on Breeze, go to the Transparency tab and change it:
  [image: Configure Breeze Transparency]
  That doesn't do anything.
- Look for transparent Breeze themes. I read somewhere that one "needs to use a theme that supports transparency". First result is always [Breeze Transparent](https://store.kde.org/p/1106232), but that's a Yakuake skin, so don't bother. Tried [KvKonqi](https://store.kde.org/p/1528879) and [Genome Dark](https://store.kde.org/p/1493288) with Kvantum. Not similar enough, and they don't respect the accent colour. They allow for some spotty transparency though (in Dolphin every other line is opaque...)
- Go to `System Settings -> Window Management -> Window Rules -> Add New...` and create a transparency rule for every window. That works, but it does not apply blur - even though in `System Settings -> Workspace Behaviour -> Desktop Effects`, `Blur` and `Background contrast` are enabled.
  There is also the `Translucency` option, and it allows me to make moving windows translucent, which works okay. They don't blur either, though.
- There is [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/e4g7me/tip_you_can_just_use_breeze_for_blur_transparency/) claiming that one can simply edit `/usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/default/metadata.desktop` and change `contrast` to a higher value. This file does not exist on my machine, but I do have a `/usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/F36/metadata.desktop` with the appropriate entry. Could not see any change.

Does anybody have a working solution?

Note that panel transparency is working, and the one app that allows transparency while respecting the blur settings is `Konsole`.

Answer (score 0):

Install Kvantum Manager.

Then navigate to: **Configure Active Theme --> Hacks**
make sure **'✓ Blur explicitly translucent windows'**. is marked as checked.

Click save, then relog.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).